# How to post selected checkboxes from order form to ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
 public List<int> myExample {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Example(ExampleModel example)
{
  return View(); 
}
```

I've a collection of checkboxes:

Razor:

```
<form method="post" action="NameController/Example">
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
       <input type="checkbox" name="myExample" value="2" />
       <input type="checkbox" name="myExample" value="5" />
       <input type="checkbox" name="myExample" value="6" />
       <input type="checkbox" name="myExample" value="7" />
    } 
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Why I'm getting checkbox value always null? 
Where I've mistake in this example?

Comment: save the state in cookie/localstorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store your selected date in cookie like below :

```
<script>
            $.cookie('datascelta', dataValue);  //set datascelta
            $.cookie('datascelta');  //get datascelta

            $.cookie('datascelta1', dataValue1);  //set datascelta
            $.cookie('datascelta1');  //get datascelta



            $(function () {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
                $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    altField: '#datascelta',
                    defaultDate: $.cookie('datascelta') ? $.cookie('datascelta') : new Date() //get the date after reload and init datepicker
                    onSelect: function (dataValue) {
                        $.cookie('datascelta', dataValue); //store the date in cookies before submiting form
                    }
                });

                $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    altField: '#datascelta1',
                    defaultDate: $.cookie('datascelta1') ? $.cookie('datascelta1') : new Date() //get the date after reload and init datepicker
                    onSelect: function (dataValue1) {
                        $.cookie('datascelta1', dataValue1); //store the date in cookies before submiting form
                    }
                });

                $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e)
                {
                    $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
                });
                $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e)
                {
                    $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: please tickmark my answer if it is helpful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should save those value in cookie, you can try this lib with Jquery
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score -1):

Javascript doesn't save data as it on run on client side. You'll need something to send data from server side as refreshing the page will clear everything from client side and will only used data from server side. You can use data from php to be used back in the input.

Declare data from php

```
<?php $date = date(); ?>
```

and then fetch back into javascript

```
var date = <?php echo $date; ?>;
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC